# igraph constraint components (c-size, c-density, c-hierarchy)

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to compute the components of Burt's constraint discussed [here](http://ronaldsburt.com/research/files/NNappB.pdf) by Burt.

Igraph's constraint command computes Burt's constraint score:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(igraph)

g <- graph.formula( "A"--------"B":"E":"F":"EGO",
                    "B"--------"A":"D":"EGO",
                    "C"--------"EGO",
                    "D"--------"B":"EGO",
                    "E"--------"A":"EGO",
                    "F"--------"A":"EGO",
                    "EGO"-"A":"B":"C":"D":"E":"F")

coords <- layout_nicely(g)

V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
g$layout <- coords
plot(g)

constraint(g)
```

[image]
Constraint only returns the overall constraint score.

[image]

with

[image]

and

[image]

[image] is the strength (= weight) of connection between two vertices i and j.

[image] is the direct connection between vertices i and j (share of connections from i to j of all of i's connections).

[image] is the sum of indirect connections between vertices i and j (connections to other vertices q that are both connected to i and j).

I want to work with the individual components c-size, c-density, and c-hierarchy.

Burt reshapes the constraint equation like this:
[image]

The first term [image] is c-size.

The second term [image] is c-density.

The third term [image] is c-hierarchy.

I want to compute the three components of constraint for each vertex of the network.

I could think of two solutions, both of which are beyond my capabilities.
Maybe there is a way to harness these values directly from igraph's constraint command.
Alternatively, one would have to compute these values manually.

For the example above, I have computed these values by hand using Excel:

| node | degrees | constraint | c-size | c-density | c-hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| A | 4 | 0.60 | 0.25 | 0.23 | 0.12 |
| B | 3 | 0.64 | 0.33 | 0.24 | 0.07 |
| C | 1 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| D | 2 | 0.78 | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.03 |
| E | 2 | 0.73 | 0.50 | 0.21 | 0.02 |
| F | 2 | 0.73 | 0.50 | 0.21 | 0.02 |
| EGO | 6 | 0.40 | 0.17 | 0.16 | 0.07 |

|  |  | strength | direct influence of j | indirect influence of j |  |  | combinded influence of j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FROM | TO | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| A | B | 1 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.17 | 0.04 | 0.09 |
| A | E | 1 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.17 | 0.04 | 0.09 |
| A | F | 1 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.17 | 0.04 | 0.09 |
| A | EGO | 1 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 1.33 | 0.33 | 0.34 |
| B | A | 1 | 0.33 | 0.33 | 0.17 | 0.06 | 0.15 |
| B | D | 1 | 0.33 | 0.33 | 0.17 | 0.06 | 0.15 |
| B | EGO | 1 | 0.33 | 0.33 | 0.75 | 0.25 | 0.34 |
| C | EGO | 1 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 1.00 |
| D | B | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.17 | 0.08 | 0.34 |
| D | EGO | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.33 | 0.17 | 0.44 |
| E | A | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.17 | 0.08 | 0.34 |
| E | EGO | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.13 | 0.39 |
| F | A | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.17 | 0.08 | 0.34 |
| F | EGO | 1 | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.13 | 0.39 |
| EGO | A | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 1.33 | 0.22 | 0.15 |
| EGO | B | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 0.75 | 0.13 | 0.09 |
| EGO | C | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.03 |
| EGO | D | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 0.33 | 0.06 | 0.05 |
| EGO | E | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 0.25 | 0.04 | 0.04 |
| EGO | F | 1 | 0.17 | 0.17 | 0.25 | 0.04 | 0.04 |

Comment: I guess you may have to follow the formulas and write specific function to compute `c-size`, `c-density` and `c-hierarchy`, since there seems no existing `igraph` function can give you immediate results.

Comment: I could do it manually in Excel, but to automate this, I would need to access an edge list like in the second table or access the adjacency matrix. My hope was, that there could be a way to look under the hood of igraph's constraint command and adapt the code.

Comment: Maybe you can check with the `C` source code of `constraint`. However, if you want to have a direct use of R code, I don't think it is feasible.